# Automatic conversion to surface reflectance (SCP)

Tags: convert, classification, landsat, reflectance, surface

I am practicing for SCP part by using Qgis 2.10.1.
I already download desired LANDSAT image from **`SCP>Download Landsat.`**

However, in *`Pre-processing`* part, after click **`Select directory`** button, the list of bands do not appeared in *`Metadata`* part for me to do the **`Perform Conversion`**.

[image]

These are the data download from **`SCP>Download Landsat`**

[image]

Is there something wrong with my data perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Sentinel-2 tab, which is wrong. You have to use Landsat tab in the preprocessing window. Then select the directory where all your bands are located.